# Select Customer Details from 1st table is customer has placed order in all categories

Tags: sql

I have 5 tables mentioned below.

**Customers**:

```
CustomerID  CustomerName        ContactName     Address         City    PostalCode  Country
1           Alfreds Futterkiste Maria Anders    Obere Str. 57   Berlin  12209       Germany
```

**Categories**:

```
CategoryID  CategoryName    Description
1           Beverages       Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales
2           Condiments      Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings
3           Confections     Desserts, candies, and sweet breads
```

**OrderDetails**:

```
OrderDetailID   OrderID     ProductID   Quantity
1       10248       11      12
```

**Orders**:

```
OrderID     CustomerID  EmployeeID  OrderDate   ShipperID
10248       90      5       1996-07-04  3
```

**Products**:

```
ProductID   ProductName SupplierID  CategoryID  Unit            Price
1       Chais       1       1       10 boxes x 20 bags  18
```

I need CustomerID, Customername and Country from Customers table only for those customers who have placed orders for all category types from categories table.

I tried following query and its working but i dont need count column in the output. Please help.

```
select a.customerid, customername, country, count(distinct d. CategoryID) 
  from customers a join orders b on a.customerid = b.customerid 
    join orderdetails c on b.orderid = c.orderid 
    join products d on c.productid = d.productid 
    join categories e on d.categoryid = e.categoryid
    join (select count(distinct f.categoryid) cnt from categories f)
 group by CustomerName
having count(distinct d. CategoryID) = cnt
```

Comment: What database system are you using? Until you decide, I am going to remove all tags.

Comment: Do not forget to specify DBMS version additionally.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.customerid, customername, country, 
  from customers a 
  where (select count(distinct d.categoryid) 
           from orders b on a.customerid = b.customerid 
              join orderdetails c on b.orderid = c.orderid 
              join products d on c.productid = d.productid)
     =  (select count(distinct f.categoryid) cnt from categories f)
```

You can do the count comparison in the where clause. Your last join isn't actually a join as it will select each time all categories.

Comment: This one is retrieving all the rows from customers table. Not giving right results. i am executing the SQL in following link.                        
 https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_distinct3

Comment: strange. I expect the `(select count(distinct f.categoryid) cnt from categories f)` to return 3 and the `select count(distinct d.categoryid)...` the number of categories linked to orders of each customer.